# Profile memory. Find memory leak in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, profile

this question was already asked a few times and I already tried some methods. Unfortunately, somehow I can't find out why my python process uses so much memory.

My setup: python 3.5.2, Windows 10, and a lot of third-party packages.

The true memory usage for the process is 300 MB ( way too much but sometimes it even explodes to 32gb)

```
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
memory_real = process.memory_info().rss/(1024*1024) #--> 300 Mb
```

What I tried so far:

- memory line profiler (didn't helped me)
- tracemalloc.start(50) and then
  `snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
  top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')
  print("[ Top 10 ]")
  for stat in top_stats[:10]:
      log_and_print(stat)`

  gives just few Mb's as result
- `gc.collect()
  import objgraph
  objgraph.show_most_common_types()`
   
  returns: 

  `function          51791
  dict              32939
  tuple             28825
  list              13823
  set               10748
  weakref           10551
  cell              7870
  getset_descriptor 6276
  type              6088
  OrderedDict       5083`

  (when the process had 200 mb's the numbers above were even higher)
- pympler: process exists with some error-code

So really struggling to find a way where the memory of the process is allocated. Do I do something wrong, or is there some easy way to find out what is going on?

PS: 
I was able to solve this problem through luck. It was a badly coded while loop, where a list was extended, without a proper break condition. 
Anyway is there a way to find such memory leaks. What I often see is that some memory profiling packages is called explicitly. In this case, I wouldn't have a chance to make a memory dump or check the memory in the main thread since the loop is never left.

Comment: Are you sure it's using the memory in the way you think it is? https://superuser.com/questions/727356/why-is-the-total-memory-usage-reported-by-windows-task-manager-much-higher-than

Comment: I'm not sure if it is 100 % correct. But definitely, when the process enters the loop (with specific values) the whole available ram is then consumed. So in general, none of the above methods could work, since the process never leaves the loop.

Comment: My point is how do you know the RAM is "consumed" and not just "tentatively reserved". It would be interesting to see what happens when you run your program in so many parallel instances that you would go out of RAM on your machine. Does it still behave the same?